# NSTimeZone and special time zone area Etc

Tags: ios, timezone, nstimezone

Is it correct to assume that `NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:` in iOS 7 accepts both time zone IDs with non-special areas (as in `America/New_York`) and with the [special area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area) (as in `Etc/UTC`) but that `NSTimeZone name` will never return the special area (but would return e.g. `Europe/London` instead)?

Who can confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's a safe assumption. On OS X, in my time zone and locale (US English, UTC-6), I can run the following code:

```
    NSTimeZone *utc = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Etc/UTC"];
    NSTimeZone *london = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/London"];
    NSLog(@"utc name = %@", [utc name]);
    NSLog(@"london name = %@", [london name]);
```

Which gives the following output:

> utc name = Etc/UTC
>
> london name = Europe/London

So If a time zone was given a special area in instantiating it, it will continue to use that with its name. As an added layer of complication, using `+timeZoneWithAbbreviation:` will also get different names, e.g.:

```
    NSTimeZone *utc2 = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
    NSLog(@"utc2 name = %@", [utc2 name]);
```

> utc2 name = GMT